# How do I add a "OR" operator to this if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this IF statement that i want to add a OR to so it should be if($variable1 ==$variable2) or if($variable3 == $variable4).

```
if($variable1 == $variable2)
die("");

else
echo("");
```

Comment: `if($variable1 == $variable2 || $var3 == $var4)` is not that hard. If you haven't read a basic programming manual, do so now.

Comment: You are not ready for SO, young padawan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [PHP Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

```
 if($variable1 ==$variable2 || $variable3 == $variable4) {
//do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($variable1 == $variable2 || $variable3 == $variable4){
die("");
}
else{
echo("");}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($variable1 == $variable2  || $variable3 == $variable4)
die("");
else
echo("");
```